# Android - offline analytics

Tags: android, google-analytics, analytics

I am looking for a solution to implement Analytics on Android devices with no internet connection at all. I know there are services like Google Analytics that provide support for analytics when there is no internet connection. But the devices we are going to deploy on would not have Internet connection at all.

This is kind of a different situation. Does any one know if we can write the analytics in log files on the devices and then later on transfer/import those log files to some kind of analyzing tool. This is something what I was thinking of. If someone has a different approach please let me know.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What sort of analytics are you collecting? Is it not something you can implement on your own, to write off to a file - or are you specifically looking to existing analytic tools?

Comment: Well, currently I am using Google Analytics.